# WWW class does not work in unity

Tags: c#, android, http, web, unity-game-engine

First of all, I'm new to Unity and I'm developing in the new Unity 5.0.0. I´ve been looking at the WWW class in Unity documentation and followed through it and haven't gotten it to work yet. I have looked in other questions and googled a lot and couldn't get it to work. This is the code I got in my APImanager:

```
using UnityEngine; using System.Collections;

public class apiManager : MonoBehaviour

{

public string url = "URL";

 public string temp;

 public void Start(){
     WWW w = new WWW (url);
     StartCoroutine (WaitForRequest (w));

 }
 IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW w){
     yield return w;
     temp = w.text.ToString ();
 }
 public string getTemp(){
     return temp;
 }

}
```

And in my main file where I want to call the string getTemp method and show the data in a label it doesn't work. Nothing shows up and I'm struggling to figure it out.  (I'm trying to show the data in the label as a text (string).)

```
public class main : MonoBehaviour {

apiManager myApiManager = new apiManager();

void OnGUI() {

GUI.Label(ScreenPosition(0, 500, 300,300), myApiManager.getTemp());

}
}
```

Can you please provide me information on how it should work or if I have missed something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating the WWW object outside of the coroutine method.  Move it within WaitForRequest:

```
    using UnityEngine; using System.Collections;

public class apiManager : MonoBehaviour

{

public string url = "URL";

 public string temp;

 public void Start(){
     StartCoroutine (WaitForRequest (w));
 }

 IEnumerator WaitForRequest(){
     WWW w = new WWW (url);
     yield return w;
     temp = w.text.ToString ();
 }
 public string getTemp(){
     return temp;
 }

}
```

Also you should not be creating a monobehavior object from within your Main monobehavior.  Instead define it as a public property and assign it within the editor (you can also use FindObjectOfType at runtime):

```
    public class main : MonoBehaviour {

public apiManager myApiManager; 

void OnGUI() {

GUI.Label(ScreenPosition(0, 500, 300,300), myApiManager.getTemp());

}
}
```

Comment: But when I move down the WWW object i get an error on  the StartCoroutine method.. Inside the brackets because the w is initialized after i call for it...

Comment: Also, I found the issue. Needed to delete the "w" since there is no parameters. But I get this error message... actually, alot of it:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
main.OnGUI () (at Assets/Scripts/main.cs:680)

Comment: Did you assign the property myApiManager to anything in the Unity editor?  You need to drag your apiManager script on a game object, then drag that game object onto the myApiManager property in the editor.  Makes sense you got a lot of errors since onGui is called a lot during runtime.

Comment: Im maybe confused. But this is not the only code I have for the game.. The game works fine and the OnGUI is also working.. Its this code i posted here which is not working properly after i made the changes now according to your reply. I get this errors as I run the game and the error message keep increasing. Its like an loop or something and need to be stopped, I dont know.

Comment: Did you assign myApiManager to anything in the Unity editor?  If no, then myApiManager is null, hence the null reference error.  OnGui is called repeatedly so you will get many of these errors.

Comment: As I explained above im new to Unity and im sorry for the questions.. I dont think I have.. In that case, how do I do it? Could you explain please? The "guide" didnt guide me much since I dont know everything in Unity..

Comment: 1) create empty game object  2) drag apiManager script onto that object  3) select the game object which has the "main" script attached  4) drag the game object you made in step #1 onto the "myApiManager" field.

Comment: also, in your OnGui method, add this line of code at the top:  if (myApiManager.getTemp() == null) return;

Comment: Thank you! I found another problem why it wasnt giving any data in the label and it was because the w.text.toString(); needed to only be w.text; When I removed the ToString(); it worked. Thank you alot!